# Summarizing multiple tables in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm hoping this is the [right site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155487/if-i-had-a-question-with-excel-which-site-would-i-use) for this question

I have a years worth of delivery receipts (60+ tables, each on a separate sheet) all with the same headings and I'd like to add them all up to a years summary table.

All I need is the `Art-No.`, `Description` and total `Delivered Quantity`, but going through every single sheet and totting them up individually is going to take a long time. Not every order will have the same products on, or in the same order. Some products may only appear once through the year while others are on every order. Its a bit of a mess.

The `Art-No.` is essentially a product ID and can be used to identify a product (as well as `Description`).

Example Table 1
[image: table headings and example text]

Example Table 2
[image]

Example Table 3
[image]

Desired Outcome Table Example[image]

I've tried using Power Query to merge but that doesn't consolidate the data, just seems to tack it on.

I've tried [pivot tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Consolidate-multiple-worksheets-into-one-PivotTable-report-3AE257D2-CA94-49FF-A481-E9FC8ADEEEB5) but they don't want to take the rang saying "Data Source reference not valid"

Is there an easier way to do this ?

Comment: Are you only interested in summarizing Art-No., Description and total Delivered Quantity, or do you also need to preserve information relating to the order (e.g. the customer)?

Comment: Just those 3 please, other information is only pertinent to that individual receipt

Comment: And since you tagged your question with "microsoft-excel-2010," I assume that is the version you are working with.

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: I thought I'd have time to fiture this out for you and give a complete answer, but it turns out I don't right now.  If no one else chimes in, I'd start by looking at PowerPivot, which is a microsoft add in for 2010.  (It's incorporated into 2013 on.)  You can download it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413462(v=sql.110).aspx#download

Comment: i gave it a go, I think having them all spaced out or something is messing it up

Comment: I would have tried to convert all files to CSV or TSV format by manual export or using `in2csv` (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bmexport, or http://stackoverflow.com/a/29831620/1921546). Then churn out information in the required format using `awk`(http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/). Finally import the output text file into excel. I do not have Microsoft Excel to create sample files.

Comment: Important question: Can we assume that there is a fixed / known table `Art-No.` and `Description`? In other words, are you able to make the result table you want with everything *except* the `Ordered qty.` and `Delivered qty.`? If so, I have a really neat solution for you.

Comment: @EngineerToast yes I believe so

Comment: So I've taken a stab at an answer that doesn't use Power Query.  You do need to know the name of each or your tables and article numbers, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you were on the right track with Power Query.  Generally, the steps are:

1. Load each table into Power Query (it's a pain, but I don't know of any bulk load option).  You can set the default option to only load the connection, so you don't have duplicate sheets with the Power Query version of each table.
2. Open your first table in Power Query Editor.  Choose **Append Queries** (not merge) from the Combine section of the Ribbon.
3. In the Append dialog box, select your second table and then OK.  Repeat for each table you've loaded to Power Query.  You're now adding the rows from each of your 60 tables into one "super table".
4. When all of your loaded tables have been added, load your Append Query to Excel.
5. Use the Append Query Table as a data source to create a Pivot Table.  Select Art-No. and Description as your row labels (format as Tablular Layout, no subtotals) and Quantity as your values.

[image: sample]

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you

Comment: Glad to help.  If you need any follow-up, just let me know.

Answer (score 4):

If all the data were in one sheet, it would be pretty easy to apply a Pivot table to it to generate the summary. Copying and pasting 60+ sheets into one would take a few minutes to do manually, but could be done.

Alternatively, you could use a macro to do the copying and pasting. Assuming each sheet starts in A1 and all the sheets contain data tables, this macro should work:

```
Sub Macro1()

NumSheets = Application.Sheets.Count
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

i = 1
Do While i <= NumSheets
    Sheets(i).Select
    If (i = 1) Then
      Range("A1").Select
    Else
      Range("A2").Select
    End If
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets(NumSheets + 1).Select
    If (i = 1) Then
       Range("A1").Select
    Else
       Range("A2").Select
       Selection.End(xlDown).Select
       ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    i = i + 1
    Loop


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that doesn't use Power Query.

For any given table, you can total the delivered quantity of a particular product (Art-No.) using **SUMIF**. For example, the following formul will give the total delivered quantity of Art-No. 59792 in a table called Table1.

```
`=SUMIF(Table1[Art-No.],"=59792",Table1[Delivered Quantity])`
```

You can use the **INDIRECT** function to pull the table name from another cell.  For example, if cell A2 contains "Table1", then the following formula will produce the same result as the one above

```
`=SUMIF(INDIRECT(A2"[Art-No.]"),"=59792",INDIRECT(A2&"[Delivered Quantity]"))`
```

So to make a new table with the total of each type of article in each table, you could do the followinig:

1. Put all the article numbers in the first row, starting at B1.
2. Put all the table names in the first column, starting at A2.
3. Copy the following into B2

=SUMIF(INDIRECT($A2&"[Art-No.]"),B$1,INDIRECT($A2&"[Delivered Quantity]"))

4. Copy B2 and paste into the rest of your table.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option that doesn't use Power Query or Pivot Tables:

As you stated in the comments, you are able to create the result table you want with everything except the `Ordered qty.` and `Delivered qty.` fields. That means all we have to do is total up the values for every sheet using `Art-no.` as the unique ID.

**Step 1:** Create a list with all the worksheet names in it. This can be done with a little VBA since there are so many sheets in your file.

```
Sub SheetNames()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Integer
    Set ws = Worksheets.Add
    For r = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        ws.Cells(r, 1).Value = Worksheets(r).Name
    Next
End Sub
```

**Step 2:** Create a named range that refers to the list of worksheet names. I turned the list into a table and based the name range on that but you don't have to.

[image: Named Range]

**Step 3:** Create your base results table without the `Ordered qty.` and `Delivered qty.` values filled in. If you don't have that available somewhere, it might be easiest to use something like what [Sir Adelaide](https://superuser.com/a/1178162/348859) posted to combine all the sheets, delete the fields you don't need, erase all the qty. values, and remove duplicates. You might wonder why you would need any of this if you just follow that method instead, but the trick in the next step is too cool to not share.

[image: Table]

**Step 4:** Write your formulas to total the data from all sheets at once. First, here's the formula you can use for `Ordered qty.`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&sheets&"'!"&"B2:B10000"),[@[Art-no.]],INDIRECT("'"&sheets&"'!"&"D2:D10000")))
```

It's a special `SUMIF` wrapped in a `SUMPRODUCT`. The key to making the `SUMIF` work with a 3D reference is the `INDIRECT` function and that list of sheets names that we made. Here are the pieces of the formula:

- `INDIRECT("'"&sheets&"'!"&"B2:B10000")` It's a standard `INDIRECT` function except that we're referencing the named range we made in Step 2 that points to a list of sheet names. This is what makes it a 3D reference. I chose `B2:B10000` but you can adjust / expand that as needed. It's easy to make the reference way larger than is required to make sure nothing is missed so long as the ranges in both `INDIRECT` functions are the same size. It needs to point to the column with `Art-no.` in the other sheets.
- `[@[Art-no.]]` Since I made my results table into a actual table in Excel, this just points to the `Art-no.` value in the current row with the formula.
- `INDIRECT("'"&sheets&"'!"&"D2:D10000")` This is the same as the other `INDIRECT` but it points to the `Ordered qty.` column.
- `SUMIF(~)` This now becomes `SUMIF(Art-no. from every sheet, Art-no. in this row, Ordered qty. from every sheet)`
- `SUMPRODUCT(~)` The `SUMIF` will return an array instead of a single value so we use this to just add up all the values in that array.

The formula for `Delivered qty.` is the same except you should change `D2:D10000` to `G2:G10000` or whatever is required to point to the column with `Delivered qty.` in the other sheets.

---

<sub>Credit where credit is due, I found this method on [CreditJet.net](https://exceljet.net/formula/3d-sumif-for-multiple-worksheets) and thought it was awesome.</sub>